# Assertion in different Languages

Tags: assertion

I've a question about using assert / assertion.

I saw / used in different languages the directive assert, but I didn't really understand
the sense behind it.

For example for Unit Tests in Java / C# it is used, I can use it, then I get red or green light (true/false) after running tests.

But in low lewel languages such as C what is the sense behind it? Whats happening behind the instruction? Is this something like Exception Handling?

Is `if(obj != null" and "assert.notNull(obj)` not the same?

Comment: `assert` can be disabled. `if(...)` cannot. Note that `Assert.notNull` isn't a standard assertion, but probably a [Spring Framework Assert method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html).

Answer (score 0):

Typically in a C environment, `assert()` is implemented so that the program terminates e.g. with `abort()` in case the condition is false.

The idea is that assertions check for invariant conditions that must always be true. If not, there's a programming error and the program is best terminated as soon as possible instead of letting it run in an inconsistent state.

It's not really exception handling: The program cannot recover from an assertion failure, and typically assertions are not used for detecting runtime errors such as allocation failures or I/O errors while exceptions are oftenused for such purposes. Some environments with built-in exception handling implement assetion failures as thrown exceptions, though.

Read more on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(computing)